Why is my Python script output going to Visual Studio's Output window from one location, but not when it gets copied somewhere else?
I am trying to run a Python project's script from within a C# project. (Both projects are within the same solution in Visual Studio.)
The following code works perfectly. The output from the Python script's print command gets output the Visual Studio's Output window. (I am just using print and Debug.WriteLine during development to confirm that the script is being run.)
        private void runPythonTest(string operation)
        {
            string fileLocation = @"[...absolute path...]\NewPythonTest\NewPythonTest.py";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = "python.exe",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", fileLocation, operation, 123, 321)
            };
            p.Start();

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

            Debug.WriteLine(output);
        }

However, I cannot actually use the absolute path when this code goes to production, as the compiled code will be installed in an unknown folder, and the Python project (and its file structure) will not be included.
For this reason, I have used Add as Link to add the Python script to an area of a C# project that will have its (relative) file structure maintained in an installation in a bin\Debug folder. I then set the following on the link:

Build Action - Content
Copy to Output Directory - Copy always

Then I rebuilt my entire solution and confirmed that the Python script file was indeed copied into bin\Debug, so I changed my C# code to find the file there:
            Assembly currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            string assemblyLocation = currentAssembly.Location;
            string fileLocation = assemblyLocation.Replace("MyCoolProject.dll", "[..a few layers of subfolders...]\\NewPythonTest.py");

Then I ran my code again. The Debug.WriteLine only wrote a blank line to the Output window. I have no idea why.
I added a File.Exists to confirm that the script file exists in the folder where I'm trying to run it, and it does.
I also opened a command line interface in that folder and checked to see if that folder has access to the Python interpreter. It does.
So then I ran the script from the command line in that folder, and it ran. (Of course, the output went to the CLI when I did this.)
I tried using the absolute path to the bin\debug location of the file, but this still had the same problem during debugging: Debug.WriteLine just printed a blank line in the Output window.
So what is going on here? I can't figure out why that file works from the command line but, during debugging, either doesn't work or works but doesn't get its output shown in the Output window for some reason (in which case, I have no indication that it's actually working).
[Note: I am including the Visual Studio tag because it's possible that I was wrong to use Add as Link and set Content and Copy always. Maybe some vital file or location reference does not get copied correctly this way.]

Have you checked if the Python interpreter is correctly installed in the latter solution?

How do I install the interpreter on a specific solution? Python is already installed generally - for example, while looking at a C# file in the solution, I can still press Alt+I to open a Python Interactive window, which works.

It turns out that this was a simple issue that had very little to do with Visual Studio or the interaction between C# and Python.
One of the folders in "[... a few layers of subfolders ...]" had a space in its name.
Using Debug.WriteLine to view the output of the Python script in Visual Studio's Output window did not show me any error. However, someone proposed another approach to me that was almost identical to my code except that it output to the console (my C# program is a console app) and wrote errors to the console:
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "python.exe";
        start.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", fileLocation, operation, 123, 321);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        start.RedirectStandardError = true;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(start) ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Process failed to start"))
        {
            string output2 = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() ?? string.Empty;
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd() ?? string.Empty;

            process.WaitForExit();

            Console.WriteLine("Output:");
            Console.WriteLine(output2);
            Console.WriteLine("Errors:");
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }

Let's say my file was located at C:\folder1\folder2\bin\Debug\my stuff\MyScript.py. The error said that it could not locate the file C:\folder1\folder2\bin\Debug\my, which made the issue pretty obvious.
The fix was just to add this line to wrap the entire string in quotation marks so that the space was read correctly:
fileLocation = "\"" + fileLocation + "\"";
